# Daily index not created

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

On my single test server with 8G of RAM (1955m to JVM) having es v 7.4, I have 12 application indices + few system indices like (.monitoring-es-7-2021.08.02, .monitoring-logstash-7-2021.08.02, .monitoring-kibana-7-2021.08.02) getting created daily. So on an average I can see daily es creates 15 indices.

today I can see only two indices are created.

```
curl -slient -u elastic:xxxxx 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v' -u elastic |  grep '2021.08.03'
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
yellow open   metricbeat-7.4.0-2021.08.03                KMJbbJMHQ22EM5Hfw   1   1     110657            0     73.9mb         73.9mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2021.08.03            98iEmlw8GAm2rj-xw   1   0          3            0      1.1mb          1.1mb
```

and reason for above I think is below,

While looking into es logs, found

`[2021-08-03T12:14:15,394][WARN ][o.e.x.m.e.l.LocalExporter] [elasticsearch_1] unexpected error while indexing monitoring document org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportException: org.elasticsearch.common.ValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [1] total shards, but this cluster currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;`

logstash logs for application index and filebeat index

`[2021-08-03T05:18:05,246][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"ping_server-2021.08.03", :_type=>"_doc", :routing=>nil}, #LogStash::Event:0x44b98479], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"ping_server-2021.08.03", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"validation_exception", "reason"=>"Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [2] total shards, but this cluster currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;"}}}}`

`[2021-08-03T05:17:38,230][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-7.4.0-2021.08.03", :_type=>"_doc", :routing=>nil}, #LogStash::Event:0x1e2c70a8], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-7.4.0-2021.08.03", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"validation_exception", "reason"=>"Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [2] total shards, but this cluster currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;"}}}}`

Adding active and unassigned shards totals to 1000

```
"active_primary_shards" : 512,
  "active_shards" : 512,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 488,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 51.2
```

If I check with below command, I see all unassigned shards are replica shards

curl -slient -XGET -u elastic:xxxx http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards | grep 'UNASSIGNED'

```
.
.
dev_app_server-2021.07.10           0 r UNASSIGNED                            
apm-7.4.0-span-000028               0 r UNASSIGNED                                                      
ping_server-2021.07.02              0 r UNASSIGNED                            
api_app_server-2021.07.17           0 r UNASSIGNED                            
consent_app_server-2021.07.15       0 r UNASSIGNED
```

Q. So for now, can I safely delete unassigned shards to free up some shards as its single node cluster?

Q. Can I changed the settings from allocating 2 shards (1 primary and 1 replica) to 1 primary shard being its a single server for each index online?

Q. If I have to keep one year of indices, Is below calculation correct?

15 indices daily with one primary shard * 365 days = 5475 total shards (or say 6000 for round off)

Q. Can I set 6000 shards as shard limit for this node so that I will never face this mentioned shard issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of unassigned shards (probably because you have a single node and all indices have replicas=1), so it's easy to get rid of all of them and get rid of the error at the same time, by running the following command

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index.number_of_replicas": 0
}
```

Regarding the count of the indices, you probably don't have to create one index per day if those indexes stay small (i.e. below 10GB each). So the default 1000 shards count is more than enough without you have to change anything.

You should simply leverage [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) in order to keep your index size at bay and not create too many small ones of them.

Comment: Hi @Val, Thanks. I am reading ILM doc for v7.4. So to verify whether ILM will really reduce the no. of shards, will consider above e.g. say each index is daily getting created of 1G, for me to keep 365 days of data, it will be 1G * 365 = 365G/yr for one index, now if I create policy to rollover index after 50G, so 365G/50G = 7,    will it mean that this index will only take 7 shards for a year? is this correct?           Similarly say, If we create policy to rollover index after 30 days, so 365/30 = 12, will it means that one index will only have 12 shards for a yr?

Comment: is above assumption correct for both scenarios i.e `rollover after 50G` or `rollover after 30 days`?

Comment: Thanks for providing some numbers. If you create 1G of data per day, I would create monthly indexes, i.e. rollover after 30 days or 30G (whichever comes first). If each index has, say, 2 primary shards (~15G each), you'd have max 24 primary shards for the whole year and that would be perfectly acceptable. Proceeding that way will keep you well under that 1000 shards per cluster limit.

Comment: Hi @Val, Thank you for your reply. Is above setting to change the no. of replicas to 0 is permanent? will new indices would only have 1 primary replica after applying this setting?                                   How can I check the settings (specifically for shards) which is getting applied to each new index that is getting created daily (may be that's called `index template`)

Comment: Yes, you need to create an index template anyway if you're going with ILM. In that template you need to set replicas to 0 (because you have a single node, so replicas are useless) and primary to 1 or 2 (preferably). If you set that up, you'll never have to worry about it anymore, unless your daily volume increases, in which case you might just have to bump up the primary shard count by 1 and be happy for another year :-)

Comment: ok I applied above setting to make replicas to 0. I see all today's index as UNASSIGNED now. Do you know why?  ```                                                                                                                                                            app_server-2021.08.04         0 r UNASSIGNED                            
dev_server-2021.08.04 0 r UNASSIGNED ```                                                                                                                                                                                  "unassigned_shards" : 11

Comment: That means the settings were not applied, as setting replicas to 0 removes all UNASSIGNED shards. What response did you get from running the command?

Comment: I see two shards for today for each index (same as before making replicas to 0) one is primary as STARTED and other is replica as `UNASSIGNED`, does that mean it still creating replica shard?

Comment: by running, `localhost:9200/_cluster/health\?pretty | grep shards` I get `"active_primary_shards" : 524` , `"unassigned_shards" : 11`